# how to calculation text number until div height?

Tags: javascript, html, text, substring

i try make book paging.

div height is 100px.

div have a long text. text is very long long string(2mb).

i want know text subString position.

how to know text length until 50px height??

Answer (score 0):

There should be a different approach

You can get the div width.

`var width= getWidth();`

Calculate how many character in a row (calculate manually), based on that width. And get the row number within 50px.

`var limit = getRowLimit();var n=getNRow();`

Do a substring.

`var subtext= mytext.substr(0,limit * n);`

Comment: um... i dont nuderstand. how to know row number and row limit?

Comment: You did not put any code in the question, the easiest one is just calculate manually and put it as a constraint.